# Diposal of SoundPlayer and Resource in C#

Tags: c#, .net, soundplayer

I am working on a kind of (at least closely related) Virtual Keyboard and want to include some clicking Sound. For testing I have just used

```
SoundPlayer player  = new SoundPlayer(Resource2.click);     
player .PlaySync();
```

Now I obviously do not want it to be Sync since it would freeze the keyboard.
Instead, if a new button gets clicked while the previous click-Sound is still playing, I would prefer the first one to stop and just start over with the new click. It is always the same sound for every button, approx. 1 sec long, but there might be a lot of events (typing speed)

So I planned to just go with

```
//Startup
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Resource2.click);
player.Load();
```

and

```
//ButtonClickEvent
player.Stop()
player.Play()
//More stuff
```

Though while looking around I found this thread:
[How to use System.Media.SoundPlayer to asynchronously play a sound file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161229/how-to-use-system-media-soundplayer-to-asynchronously-play-a-sound-file)

My way of doing it would be his Attempt #1, but he seems to have a problem:"SoundPlayer and the embedded resource stream are not immediately disposed".
Now I am not quite sure what is meant by this. Does this only concern memory issues if I have many different SoundPlayer objects? Or is this something else which might give me problems on the long term, which I did not see in my first tests. This is my main question. Additionally: Is there something else I overlooked that might give problems once in a while? E.g. stopping the player while it is not running multiple times?

Comment: You should make sure the resources are _eventually_ disposed, yes.

Comment: After every Playing of the Sound or before shuting down? So this is just what is not clear to me. If I use SoundPlayer.Stop() and then just start again with .Play() on the same SoundPlayer object, I expected it to not use up additional memory, such that I can just do this. Or is it running full my memory and will crash finally if I do so?

Comment: You just can't use SoundPlayer to do this reliably, you'll have to prevent the user from pressing another key until the sound is done playing.  At one second that is not reasonable.  Either get the click sound down to ~50 msec or use an audio class that can use the mixer.

Comment: Hi, thank you! First of all I am still not sure where exactly the problem is, if using soundplayer. Is is only the resource disposal problem, that it uses up memory on every call of play? If so, shouldn't I be able to get rid of it by doing as above, but getting the wav from a file instead of a Resource?
Or is there more behind it? Timing problems or something like that?
Can you recommend a proper alternative for my problem? 
Thanks a lot!